# Продублировать в новую строку нечетные символы

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте) Нужно продублировать из строки st1 в st2 символы имеющие нечетный код ASCII.
Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Поочередно, проверяя на четность...

Comment: Циклами. А вообще покажите что у вас получилось не так.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void duplicateOddChars(std::string st1, std::string &st2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < st1.length(); i++) {
        if ((int)st1[i] % 2 == 1) {
            st2 += st1[i];
            st2 += st1[i];
        } else {
            st2 += st1[i];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string st1 = "Hello, World!";
    std::string st2;

    duplicateOddChars(st1, st2);

    std::cout << st2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: я пробовала так: char st1[] = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
    char st2[22]; сразу скопировала строку st1 в st2 чтобы потом просто поменять, далее идет цикл, как для одномерного массива, но выдает кучу ошибок связанных с разными типами (значение типа "char *" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "int")